# Locating individual class instances from values in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop

I'm trying to print out a set of coordinates from a class. Each instance of this class has 3 values: longitute, latitude, and IP address. I'm reading from a log file that logs source and destination IP addresses of various cyber attacks. When I read an IP address from the log file, is there a way for JS to recognize that an IP address belongs to an instance of a class, and then print future class values based on which class it recognizes? What is the best way to do this? Can this be solved by JQuery?

```
class comp {
    constructor(ipa, long, lat){
        this.address = ipa;
        this.long = long;
        this.lat = lat;
        ips.push(address);
    }
    getlong(){
        return this.long;
    };
    getlat(){
        return this.lat;
    }
    getip(){
        return this.address;
    }
    setlatlong(inputLong, inputLat){
        this.long = inputLong;
        this.lat = inputLat;
        return;
    }
    setip(inputIP){
        this.address = inputIP;
    }
};

comp1 = new comp('10.0.0.1', '-77.050636', '38.889248');
comp2 = new comp('10.0.0.2', '-78.050636', '39.889248');
```

```
//obj = ip addresses
function process(obj){
    ///
    if (ids.includes(obj.id)) {
            ids.push(obj.id);
            hits.push( { origin : { latitude: comp1.getlat(), longitude: comp1.getlong() },
            destination : { latitude: comp2.getlat(), longitude: comp2.getlong() } } );
        }
};
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get what you mean, but you could use [**static properties**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Public_static_fields). This is a pure JS solution, though.

Also you're probably aware of this, but as per OOP norm, I advise you to use [Pascal case](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pascal_case) to name classes, so I took the liberty of renaming it accordingly.

#### Pure JS Solution

```js
class Comp {

    // declare static array
    static instances = [];

    constructor(ipa, long, lat) {
        this.address = ipa;
        this.long = long;
        this.lat = lat;

        // to access static properties, use Class.property syntax
        // populates the class's instances array with every new instance
        Comp.instances.push(this);

        ips.push(this.address);
    }

    // static method to retrieve instance based on IP
    static getInstance(ip) {
        return Comp.instances.find(v => v.address == ip, null);
    }

    getlong(){
        return this.long;
    };
    getlat(){
        return this.lat;
    }
    getip(){
        return this.address;
    }
    setlatlong(inputLong, inputLat){
        this.long = inputLong;
        this.lat = inputLat;
        return;
    }
    setip(inputIP){
        this.address = inputIP;
    }
};

comp1 = new Comp('10.0.0.1', '-77.050636', '38.889248');
comp2 = new Comp('10.0.0.2', '-78.050636', '39.889248');

console.log(Comp.getInstance('10.0.0.1')); // prints comp1
```

Now here's the bit I couldn't really get. Doesn't make sense checking the array for an IP and then pushing it again if true.

So I figured you just want each IP to be instantiated once, so...

```js
// source and target objects
function process(src, tgt){
    // gets instance of src, if it exists; else creates new one
    let comp1 = Comp.getInstance(src.ipa) || new Comp(src.ipa, src.long, src.lat);
    // gets instance of tgt, if it exists; else creates new one
    let comp2 = Comp.getInstance(tgt.ipa) || new Comp(tgt.ipa, tgt.long, src.lat);
    hits.push({
            origin: { latitude: comp1.getlat(), longitude: comp1.getlong() },
            destination : { latitude: comp2.getlat(), longitude: comp2.getlong() }
        });
};
```

You can execute `console.log(Comp.instances)` on your console to check the stored addresses and coordinates. Another possible idea, if it makes sense, would be throwing an exception if one is trying to instantiate a dupe IP.